# How to load HTML file with external link to CSS file with wxPython?

Tags: python, html, css, wxpython, wxhtmlwindow

I'm trying to load an Html file with wx.html.HtmlWindow. The Html file is linked to an external style sheet (CSS) file.
The problem is the Html window only shows the plain Html file without styling (colors, fonts, etc.)
How can I solve this issue?

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Embedded Style Sample</title>
<link href="E:\pythonGUI\styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/></head>
<body>
<h1>Embedded Style Sample testing</h1>
<h2>Next Line</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
h1{
    color: #0000FF;
  }
  h2{
    color: #00CCFF;
  }
```

[image: the Html file on browser]

Python code:

```
import  wx 
import  wx.html
import  wx.html2 
  
class MyHtmlFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(
            self, 
            parent, 
            -1, 
            title, 
            size = (600,400)
        )
        html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self) 
        html.LoadPage("E:\\pythonGUI\\newtest.html") 

app = wx.App()  
frm = MyHtmlFrame(None, "Simple HTML File Viewer")  
frm.Show()  
app.MainLoop()
```

the Html file show on HTML window:

[image: the Html file show on HTML window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want complete HTML/CSS support as well as a Javascript engine, consider using [wx.html2.WebView](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.html2.WebView.html#wx-html2-webview) instead.

From wxpython docs:

> wx.html doesn’t really have CSS support but it does support a few
> simple styles: you can use "text-align", "width", "vertical-align" and
> "background" with all elements and for SPAN elements a few other
> styles are additionally recognized:
>
> ```
> color
>
> font-family
>
> font-size (only in point units)
>
> font-style (only “oblique”, “italic” and “normal” values are supported)
>
> font-weight (only “bold” and “normal” values are supported)
>
> text-decoration (only “underline” value is supported)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using wx.html2.WebView instead of wx.html.HtmlWindow:

```
import wx
import wx.html2

class About(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,None,-1,title="Title",size=(700,700))

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,title,pos,size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,title,pos,size)
        self.tester=wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
        self.tester.LoadURL("E:\\pythonGUI\\newtest.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = Test("html2 web view", (20, 20), (800, 600))
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```